# php soapclient to c#

Tags: c#, soap, client

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://www.progez.com/demo/webservice/wsHotel.sh",'uri' => "http://www.progez.com/demo/", 'encoding' =>"ISO-8859-9"));
$parm['login'] = "USERNAME";
$parm['pass'] = "PASSWORD";
$parm['agency_code'] = "ADM";
$parm['letters'] = "bodrum";
$inf =($client->__soapCall("destinationListByLetterV2",array($parm)));

print_r($inf);

?>
```

How to code convert c# ?

Answer (score 0):

You start by generating a strongly typed proxy using the [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) or [Add Service reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) dialog in Visual Studio by pointing to the web service WSDL. This will generate a strongly typed client allowing you to consume the service. And then consume:

```
using (var client = new SomeServiceClient())
{
    var result = client.destinationListByLetterV2("USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "ADM", "bodrum");
}
```

Comment: this service not wsdl :( webrequest and webresponse can solve the problem?

Comment: @Emre AKAY, hmm, it could be a PITA to consume a service without a WSDL. You will basically need to resort to low level HttpClient API and simulate what's going on under the covers.